# How to change C# RDLC Text box position dynamically

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I want to change the RDLC Report element location dynamically. but there is no such option to do so..

How to change the RDLC report lable position (Location) dynamically

Comment: RDLC is HTML format so you should use a HTML parser.  It would be similar to editing a webpage dynamically.  You would locate a tag and then modify the tag.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback.  but this is regarding windows application

Comment: So What?  It is HTML and any HTML editor should do the task.  You can even manually change the position manually.  This is an issue with a non robust application package.  Complain to the manufacturer.